# How to Structure the XML code

Tags: xml, notepad++

Goal:
Make XML source code to be structured in a userfriendly approach based the "requested result"

Problem:
I have a large size of a xml data and all data and sorcecode is in 1 row only. A large width size at one row only.

How should I enable to make the xml code to be structured according to the simple without manual work? It would be create to press a button and everything would be structured according to the picture.

Information:
*I'm using notepadd++ and unfortunately there is no functionality unless you have a proof.

[image]

Comment: You can try "word wrap", if you just have to view it, not save it

Answer (score 1):

1) ctrl+f

2) Click on replace tab

3) check that Extended checkbox is checked

4) In find type ><

5) In replace type >\n<

6) click on Replace All button!

[As shown in figure use it in notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/befyJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print (libXML) or (XML only - with line breaks Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B)